# How to glue files in gulp?

Tags: javascript, gulp

I'm using concat now:

```
Gulp.task ('compileJS', function () {
Return gulp.src (['./ js / api.js',' ./js/dt.js', './js/index.js','js/main.js','js/lib/kendo -ui / kendo.all.min.js'])
.pipe (concat ('all.js'))
.pipe (gulp.dest ('./ dist /'));
});
```

It is necessary to permanently prescribe the path to the files in the config file.
If you specify * .js, then the gluing sequence may break, in other words, there may be a jquery module at first, but only after that the jquery itself

Is it possible to do this (can there be a plugin of which) what would it look Index.html searched for all the sections `<script>`, took the file and glued it sequentially?

Sorry for bad english, but I hope you understand me

Comment: if you have used bower or npm for dependencies it would be easier

Comment: then you could concat  js under node_modules or bower_components together and put it first and you concat the source seperately